# php - Slider not working in front-page.php in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I was using a javascript and php slider in html code when it went into wordpress it never worked when it was in html it worked now it says No images found for this slideshow.

header.php javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myslides').cycle({
    fit: 1, pause: 0.3
});
});
</script>
```

front-page.php slider php code

```
<?php
$directory = 'images/slideshow/';   
try {       
// Styling for images   
echo "<div id=\"myslides\">";   
foreach ( new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $item ) {            
    if ($item->isFile()) {
        $path = $directory . "/" . $item;   
        echo "<img src=\"" . $path . "\" height='200' width='800' />";  
    }
}   
echo "</div>";
}   
catch(Exception $e) {
echo 'No images found for this slideshow.<br />';   
}
?>
```

Comment: `$directory = 'images/slideshow/';`  according to this, your images should be stored in `/wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME/images/slideshow/` is that the correct path?

Comment: yes that is the correct path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WordPress you have to use `get_template_directory()` to get the path to theme directory, so your directory variable should be:

```
$directory = get_template_directory() . '/images/slideshow/';
```